# Change Header background based on category selected

Tags: php, css, background, header

I need a be able to change the header background on a cubecart v5 on different categories.

So When for example Category 1 is selected I need header background to change to cat1.jpg and for it to stay the same when a product is selected. This is needed for each of the category.

this is how the category url looks

```
index.php?_a=category&cat_id=1
```

and this is how the product url looks

```
index.php?_a=product&product_id=1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about doing it, so this may not suit your needs perfectly:

Assuming the header is not part of the content, it should not be an `<img>` tag. We should use the CSS `background` property on `<header>` or the `<div id="header">` element.

So, in your template where you have your header, you do create a CSS class with the category ID.

```
<div id="header" class="cubecart-category cubecart-category-<?php print $catID; ?>">
```

If this prints out `cubecart-category-5`, lets say, our CSS will look like this:

```
.cubecart-category {
    height: 100px;
    width: 980px;
    ...
    background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.cubecart-category-5 {
    background-image: url(cat5.jgp);
}
.cubecart-category-6 {
    background-image: url(cat6.jgp);
}
```

You could then just put a default image on the class `cubecart-category` and let it be overridden.

I know this is a generic answer, but is it of any help to you? Let me know.

Comment: I have tried to implement this with no luck any suggestions. I can supply anything you need to see. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: Where does this fail for you?

Comment: It just did not work I used the code you supplied the same header background image would appear.

Comment: My answer is sadly not a solution on its own, it is merely an example of how you can implement it. It needs tweaking. What does the relevant parts of your code look like?